# css background size cover

Tags: html, css

Hei. This sounds simple but it's not if you deal with dynamic content.
I have a container with a background image that covers the container. 
On hover the background-size should be 2% bigger (or the other way around. doesn't really matter)
Is there any way to achieve this?

```
.container
   background-size: 102% !important //here it should be cover + 2%
   background-position: center
   +transition(all 0.3s ease-in-out)
.container:hover
   background-size: 100% !important //here it should be cover
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want, could create a demo in **Snippet** or [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: And dynamic in what way generated by **JavaScript** or **Backend** (Like: PHP....)?

Comment: is background-size: 102% 102%; not working on hover.. ? (It will stretch the background to cover)

Comment: That code you've supplied should be css? if so you are missing curly brackets. Post some fiddle.

Comment: @divy3993 generated on backend. its for a cms system so I don't know what kind of images I have there...

Comment: @prateek not if I don't know the image size beforehand. 102% might not be enough for both directions as I don't know the size of the image beforehand

Comment: It's hard to answer without [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) .

Comment: @suMi Do you want [this](https://jsfiddle.net/divy3993/g4LgoLzd/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid you cannot manipulate the cover property with calc or anything of that sort to achieve your 102% manipulation. The way I see it you have two options. One is to use JavaScript and mimic cover's behavior, the other is to set the image to a pseudo element within this container. Something like this.

```
.container {
   position: relative;
   overflow: hidden;
   width: ###;
   height: ###;
}

.container:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url('bg.png') cover center;
}

.container:hover:before {
  transform: scale(1.02);
}
```

It might be a bit of a hassle to fight with the content of your container, however the easiest thing you can do it create another absolutely positioned `.content` div inside it, that just spans the entire area.

Comment: and also a **content: " ";** to **before**'s styling so that you can see the image

Comment: I used what you wrote under your solution. using a container around my image that I'm scaling. thanks!

Comment: @bulanmaster Added. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making it 2% bigger, could you instead just make it a set size. Would be a lot easier to set the size and then you could make it exactly what you want.

E.G.

```
background-size: 120px 100px;
background-position: center;
```

etc

Comment: I don't think you understood the question. He wants the image to `cover` the div, but when said div is hovered the image should "zoom-in" with 2%, while still having the cover property applied.